# VS 2012 SSIS Catalog Deploy Wizard not allowing path selection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have a vs2012 integration service project that I moved from it's initial development PC to a new laptop.  I have created the ssisdb and a new catalog on the new laptop.  When I attempt to deploy the project and packages to the catalog via the wizard, I select ssis catalog and enter my server (the new laptop), but it does not have a folder in the catalog to select a path.  The wizard doesn't have the normal button to create  a new folder either so I cannot complete the deployment wizard.  Has anyone seen this behavior and have a resolution for it?

Comment: Need more concrete details (server name, folder, ispac name). A picture, perhaps, of what the deployment screen looks like that doesn't have the create folder button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by rebuilding the project.  After rebuild, the wizard showed the Add New Folder button on the dialog and I was able to successfully publish the packages and project.  Note that a **build** on the project did not work, a **rebuild** was necessary.

I can only assume that a rebuild clears out cache that was holding info from the previous server's catalog; this apparently changed the wizard properties to allow me to add a new folder to the new server's catalog.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I made sure that actual file name is the same as you can see in your project. Capitalization also matters, in my case actual file name was in all capitals, but in solution if was Camel Case